# How to host a TCP / UDP service on the Internet which is currently running on my local machine?

Tags: hosting, tcp, udp

I have created a TCP server and it's currently hosted  on my local machine, but I want to host it on Internet like we host websites. Is there any company which  provides this service? And what's the procedure? 
I am a beginner, so please tell me the reason if you down vote.

Comment: Dooby, welcome to SF, but you really do need to read the FAQ before posting any more questions.  This one's partly off-topic because it's a request for product/service recommendations, which aren't allowed anywhere on StackExchange including SF, and partly because this site is, according to the about document linked from the bottom of every page, a "question and answer site for professional system and network administrators", and if you will forgive me, your question makes me doubt that you are one such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any VPS, dedicated system, or colocation service will allow you to run arbitrary executables of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your infromation , So I can run my Console application on a Dedicated server ? , is that right ?